# Wake up monitor from standby and show the screen without blocking further standby [Ubuntu 16.04]

Tags: command-line, 16.04, suspend, monitor, wakeup

After some time the monitor goes to standby mode. I want to wake up the monitor by a shell script. I already can wake up the monitor itself by `xset -display "$DISPLAY" dpms force on`. But I only see a black screen with the mouse pointer. And as side effect it does not go to sleep after another couple of minutes.

What I want is to wake the monitor and Ubuntu like when I move the mouse or press any key but without really doing this! So xdotool is not a solution. I see whats going on on the screen and after some minutes it goes to sleep again.

How to get this done?

Comment: Do you have wired USB keyboard and mouse?

Comment: Yes. I'm currently trying a solution by using the mouse using xdotool. But this could cause side effects.

Comment: I've favorited your question and will try to look at `xdotool` tonight.

Comment: xdotool works. The side effect: It is a user input. I need a solution that doesn't use mouse or keyboard.

Comment: I took a quick peek at `xdotool`. It's not a package I want to install and learn. Hopefully someone else here is using it and can provide support, alternatively you might want to post your question to the developer (if possible).

Comment: Still no solution for this. I searched now for DBus signals. Thought there would be a wake signal or something. But didn't find one.

Comment: I posted an answer below and would like to know if you've had a chance to try it.

Answer (score 5):

The only thing I could find on your situation was this webpage ([Can't wake up monitor once dpms put it into sleep](https://bbs.archlinux.org/viewtopic.php?id=215930)) from Archlinux. It's a long read but at the very bottom one poster recommends your script say this:

```
sleep 1 && xset dpms force standby && sleep 8 && xset dpms force on
```

Note this user tip implies it is based on having turned off DRI3 in `/etc/X11/xorg.conf.d/20-intel.conf` and using DRI2:

```
Section "Device"
   Identifier  "Intel Graphics"
   Driver      "intel"
   Option "DRI" "2"
EndSection
```

Please note this is the best I could come up with for your problem and felt compelled to post it because there have been no other answers. Since I can't reproduce your problem I have no idea if it will work for you as it has for others.

If it doesn't work I encourage you to google as much as you can using appropriate keywords.

Comment: As it is a generic OS image for different PC hardware this is not a way I want to go.